# How can I use my own Key to encrypt data using ECDiffieHellmanCng

Tags: vb.net, encryption, cryptography, diffie-hellman

My task is to encrypt data using the Elliptic Curve Cryptography in .Net (specific from client), I tried using the sample from Microsoft but it seems to generate its own key everytime.

I need to use my own key for this process, like creating a password "S3curEChaNNel_01?" and converting it to byte then use as a key, but i cant find a way to do this.

```
Using alice As New ECDiffieHellmanCng()
    Dim abData() As Byte
    Dim Str = txtKey.Text 'custom password
    abData = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Str)
    Str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(abData)

    Dim bobPublicKey() As Byte
    Dim bobKey() As Byte
    Dim bob As New ECDiffieHellmanCng()

    bob.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash
    bob.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256
    bobPublicKey = bob.PublicKey.ToByteArray()
    bob.HmacKey = abData

    bobKey = bob.DeriveKeyMaterial(CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.Sha256))
    'at this line i get an exception, "The requested operation is not supported."

    'Dim aliceKey As Byte() = alice.DeriveKeyMaterial(CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.Sha256))
    Dim encryptedMessage As Byte() = Nothing
    Dim iv As Byte() = Nothing
    txtOutput.Text = ByteArrayToString(Encrypt(bobKey, txtPlainStr.Text, encryptedMessage, iv))
End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two different things together.

When you want your own password, the person you're sending the encrypted data with such password, must know the password in order decrypt it. But you can not send the password, because the [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) could catch it.

That's why you use Diffie - Hellman.
Basically, Diffie - Hellman outputs only a number, but this number can't be used as the encryption key, because it's to weak.

Now here is where [KDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) (Key Derivation Function) comes in.
For example [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2). It takes password and salt as parameters and outputs derived key which is used to encrypt and decrypt the data you want to send.

So you take the exchanged number, pass it as a password to the KDF.
As salt you can use Alice's or Bob's IP for example.

The KDF will produce the same strong password on both sides to encrypt and decrypt the data.

Hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for sighting this, but is it possible to use my own key? If yes, then how? Thanks

Comment: It is possible possible for sure, but Diffie Hellman is used to exchange keys, not to send your password securely to the other side. 
You can just use your password `S3curEChaNNel_01` as a parameter to the KDF and derive key from that. However there is no way (at least from what I know) to send the passsword securely to the other side. 
I suppose the person you are sending the data to does not know the password.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Finally working but is there a way i can set a fixed hmac? Whenever the value is encypted, the hmac always changes to a new one, i will like it fixed when i encrypt the same  value with the same key. Thanks

Comment: The HMAC changes for every DH session (for every unique exchanged key). Don't try to reuse it. It's a part of the KDF algo and you really don't want to mess with it unless you are sure you know what you are doing. The algo is based on descreet math and it's really complicated.